# Jmeter-Transfer a file from server ( using ssh sftp) to local

Tags: jmeter

I need to copy file from remote server to local and trying it by using **SSH SFTP** using **JMETER**.I gave login credentials and in "File Transfer" section , selected
Actions-- PUT
source path -- remote path ( /ftp/xxx/yyy)
Destination -- local path.

Received error as `

java.io.FileNotFoundException: **C:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin**\ftp\xxx\yyy)

So I changed the **Actions-- GET** in View results tree for SSH SFTP response I see data of file,
**but file is not copied to local directory**

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All the parts of the "Destination path" **must exist**, i.e. you need to create all `/ftp/xxx/yyy` folder structure using [mkdir](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) command like:

   ```
   mkdir -p /ftp/xxx/yyy
   ```
2. The user which executes JMeter must have write permissions to the destination path, give him the appropriate permissions using [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod) command
3. You need to set "Print file content" to `false`

   [image]

More information: [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter)

Also [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response .. As suggested I changed the " Print File Content" to False then it worked.